Approach for Proxying WebSocket Secure (WSS) Connections
I'm currently working on a project where I have a WebSocket Secure (WSS) server and a WSS client. The client establishes a WebSocket connection over TLS to the server, which enables bi-directional communication between them. Now, I need to introduce a proxy between the client and the server to relay WebSocket traffic. There may be multiple proxies between client and server
Setup Details:

Client: Communicates with the server using WebSocket Secure (wss://), meaning all traffic is encrypted using TLS.
Server: A WSS server that receives WebSocket connections over TLS.

What I Know So Far:

CONNECT Proxy: I understand that a CONNECT proxy can be used for tunneling HTTPS connections via an HTTP CONNECT method. This method can be extended to WebSocket connections, where the proxy creates a TCP tunnel for encrypted traffic without interfering with the actual data. This provides end-to-end encryptions. I have experimented with CONNECT proxy and I understand this a little bit.
MIMT Proxy: In a Man-in-the-Middle (MITM) scenario, the proxy performs TLS termination (decrypt, inspect, and re-encrypt traffic) and establishes new TLS sessions with client and server and acts as a middleman.
Reverse Proxy:
Another option, from what I have read, seems to be setting up a reverse proxy to handle the WebSocket connection. Something like NGINX or following proxies https://github.com/koding/websocketproxy/blob/master/websocketproxy.go
https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httputil#ReverseProxy.ServeHTTP

Since reverse proxy sits in front of the (wss) server and opens a new wss connection with wss server, isn't this like MIMT. I understand reverse proxy may also provide load balancing capabilities, SSL termination among others.
Could someone please help me understand the difference between Reverse proxy and MIMT?
Thanks in advance for any guidance or insights you can provide!

please don't cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79096704/approach-for-proxying-websocket-secure-wss-connections"Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

@gnat Hi, I was told that my question is more suitable here. The question is marked for closure on stackoverflow. Let me check if I can close the question there.

You need only delete one of the questions, which you can do yourself. I suggest deleting the one on Stack Overflow, and then [edit] this post to focus on a single question. All Stack Exchange communities have a policy limiting posts to a single question.

I have already deleted the question on Stack Overflow. I will update this question. Thanks!

I don't think there's any difference between your "MITM" and "Reverse Proxy" scenarios. However, the term "MITM" is mostly used in the context of security and threat modelling, so may be misleading in an implementation-focused context. Similarly, thinking about TLS too much will be a red herring here, as WSS sits on top of existing HTTPS infrastructure. I once wrote a custom WebSocket proxy because I needed to inject some authentication messages into the protocol that was being transported via WebSocket, and found it fairly easy to get to work (< 200 lines of Python for actual proxy).

Hi @amon, thanks for the reply. In my scenario, the proxy needs to be installed where the wss client is present. So, I guess it can't be called a Reverse Proxy which is generally installed where the server is present. Now, like I have mentioned, when I try to access, wss or https through a proxy, a CONNECT request is sent to a proxy where I could setup my proxy to do MITM instead of CONNECT proxying. In this case the proxy establshes a new wss connection with the server and there is no end-to-end TLS unlike CONNECT proxying. So, what do we call the proxy in this context?

Also, when you say I once wrote a custom WebSocket proxy... - Just to clarify, you didn't send a CONNECT request to the proxy server?  So, no CONNECT proxying or MIMT (lets call it MIMT for now).
You built a proxy that opened a new wss connection to server on client's behalf. The TLS termination was done at proxy itself and the proxy created another TLS connection with wss server?

If a proxy is client-side it would usually be called just a "proxy", sometimes "forward proxy" to distinguish it from a "reverse proxy" that sits in front of a server. Any proxy or MIT that wants to inspect of modify HTTPS/WSS connection contents must perform TLS termination. CONNECT proxies transport an (encrypted) connection over HTTP, and are typically used to mask VPN connections as HTTP – they're not inherently related to WSS, except that WS also uses HTTP CONNECT. The reverse proxy I wrote was a HTTP server that terminated TCP/TLS/HTTP and forwarded the WS text frames / binary frames.
